# How to Arrange Figures as follows for a Journal Paper

Tags: floats

I want to add 3 pictures to a journal paper as shown in the image below.
[image]

I have used the following code:

```
\begin{figure*}[!h]
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \multirow{3}{*}{}
    &   \includegraphics[height=0.7in]{image b} \\
    & (b) \\
    \includegraphics[width=5in]{image a} &   \includegraphics[height=0.85in]{image c} \\
    (a)                                             & (c)
\end{tabular}
\caption{Detailed Schematic of Proposed D-LCM is shown in (a), Characteristics of signal, $V_{S}$ and $V_{A}$ for a dual-regime D-LCM is shown in (b) and (c) respectively.}
\end{figure*}
```

Up on execution I get this :
[image]

Please Help Me,
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it must work for You (is it what You need?):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a.png}}\\ (a)
\end{tabular}\qquad % some space
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-b.png}}\\ (b)
\\[0.1cm]
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-c.png}}\\ (c)
\end{tabular}
\caption{Detailed Schematic of Proposed D-LCM is shown in (a), Characteristics of signal, $V_{S}$ and $V_{A}$ for a dual-regime D-LCM is shown in (b) and (c) respectively.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this solution worked :) Thank You So Much :)